# Problem with Promise.all() and .map, unexpected results

Tags: node.js, dictionary, asynchronous, promise

I have read everything I can about promises, I tested multiple solutions from multiple threads but I cant still get it to work

I'm trying to iterate over files in a folder, grab the xml content, convert it to a js object using xml-js module then add them to an array.
This is my last attempt (one out of about 30)

```
fs.readdir(folderPath, async(err, files) => {
    let xmlArray = await Promise.all(
        files.map((file) => {
            fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', async(err, data) => {
                return await xmljs.xml2js(data , {compact : true).RequestFileHatasDM;
            })
        })
    )
    console.log(xmlArray);
})
```

What am I missing?
I thought readdir is getting called, then the callback returns and that's where I await a Promise.all, then using .map to iterate over everything and return the value, which should (?) return with a promise to resolve.

Then after everything resolved, only then it should continue to the console.log(), but for some reason the moment I run the server it immediately jumps to console.log(), as if all the promises already resolved!

When putting console.log() inside the readFile method, it was still running.

I'm confused, can anybody care to point out my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of code can be very confusing. It can make it easier to create a function that will return a Promise and accepts the file path as an input.

We can use [Util.Promisify](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html) to create a promisified version of [fs.readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback), it's easier to read the resulting code and is also more compact.

We can then use Promise.all on the result of mapping the file paths through this function.

For example:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path')
const xmljs = require('xml-js');
const { promisify } = require ('util');

const readFilePromise = promisify(fs.readFile);
const readDirPromise = promisify(fs.readdir);

// Replace as appropriate.
const folderPath = 'test_dir';

async function xmlFile2js(path) {
    const data = await readFilePromise(path, { encoding: 'utf-8'});
    return xmljs.xml2js(data, { compact: true});
}

async function readXmlFiles(folderPath) {
    try {
        const files = await readDirPromise(folderPath);
        const filePaths = files.map(file => path.join(folderPath, file));
        const promiseArray = filePaths.map(filePath => xmlFile2js(filePath));
        const xmlArray = await Promise.all(promiseArray);
        return xmlArray;
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("readXmlFiles: An error occurred:", err);
    }
}

async function testReadXmlFiles() {
    const xmlArray = await readXmlFiles(folderPath);
    console.log("testReadXmlFiles: xmlArray:", JSON.stringify(xmlArray, null, 4));
}

testReadXmlFiles();
```

Comment: This one worked!
I understand the code, but I would love if you can point out the mistakes on the original code, as I want to learn from my mistakes aswell

Comment: Thanks for testing my answer! I think the main issue with the original code is using fs.readFile in the map call, because it does not return a Promise. Hence the need to create the wrapper function xmlFile2js. Also, we needed to use path.join(file, folderPath) to create each filePath.

Comment: I see!
I am now experiencing other issue, I tried moving the whole code into a seperate async method called generateCompleteXmlFile, then calling it from server.js whenever a file is being added to the folder (using watched)
I changed the ```console.log(xmlArray)``` to ```return xmlArray``` and awaited it, but it does not await.
Any idea why?
looks somewhat like this:
```let result = await xmljs.generateCompleteXmlFile()``` then ```console.log(result)```
result is undefined

Comment: I added a callback to generateCompleteXmlFile and it fixed it, is that the right practice though?

Comment: A callback is fine, the result will be passed presumably as one of the parameters. It's not bad practice as such, the only criticism might be mixing promises and callbacks in the same function.

Comment: Then How would I resolve such case with promises only?
When I tried to ```await``` like such ```let result = await xml2js.generateCompleteXmlFile()``` and the next line I did ```console.log(result)``` i received ```undefined``` almost instantly, it did not wait and I could not figure out why

Comment: I've updated my answer to create a testReadXmlFiles function that will return the array of converted files. I think this should do what you wish!

Comment: First of all, thanks for taking that much of your free time to help!
I already tried your way, but for some reason the ```await``` does not work and ```console.log("testReadXmlFiles:...)``` resolves instantly, with ```undefined```, that's why I was so confused and resorted to a callback

Comment: Hmm, is an error occurring? I'd test perhaps with one or two simple xml files just to see what the output is. We may be seeing an error being swallowed, but it's all working with some simple xml files for me. I suspect the difference may be there!

Comment: I now recognize you also promisified the readdir method, which is the only difference between the codes, I'll test and update!

Comment: Yes, its working!
so we had to promisify readdir in order to await it, right?
but afaik, every async function returns a promise, so why did we even need to promisify each of those functions?

Comment: That's right, every async function returns a promise, however the only way we can _await_ the result of fs.readdir or fs.readFile is to promisify them. We cannot use await with the callback versions of these functions, that's the core point!

Comment: Understood, tbanks!
I had a small issue with memory (handling 5 xml files with over 50k rows each and converting them to a js object is tough, apparently) but after extending the maximum memory everything is working properly, thank you so much for the help!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things here. First Promise.all takes an array of promises which you're not giving it. Within your files.map you're not returning anything in that map callback function. So try this:

```
files.map((file) => {
        return fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', async(err, data) => {
            return await xmljs.xml2js(data , {compact : true).RequestFileHatasDM;
        })
    })
```

Also when you are returning a promise in an async function you can just do:

```
return xmljs.xml2js()
```

instead of:

```
return await xmljs.xml2js()
```

Easy thing to miss. I would encourage you to setup a debug environment so you can step through the function and watch different values in your code. It can really save you some time debugging code.

I like VSCodes debugger:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging

Comment: Hello!
I have been trying to get it working but to no avail, I tried setting static paths and not using readdir and the promise never resolved, when using the same code as above and adding return I still got an undefined array.

@Terry's answer worked perfectly fine, but I wanted to get it working without using promisify to understand promises better.

Can you please elaboratae on your answer?

Comment: Sorry I should have actually reviewed my answer a little more than I did. @Terry's answer is a pretty nice solution. Using promises with callbacks is two different styles and makes for very confusing code. Promisifying methods like readFile is a nice way to keep it all in one style.

Depending on which version of node you are using you could take a look at this. 

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api

It just takes care of promisify part.